# non-fair ReentrantReadWriteLock write and read lock priorities

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, readwritelock

If I understand correct if I use `fair mode`

read and write locks doesn't have priorities and all locks will be acquired on order of the requesting by other threads. After write request receiving - if

But I am not sure about **non-fair** mode. As written in concurrency in practice it is some sort of random.

But I am not fully inderstand this.

If I understand correct most profit of usage RWL that readers can read in parallel.

But Lets imagine that we have a lot of read operations. Lets say several threads constantly hold read lock(single read is not long but two neighbours read always overlaps). And sometimes write operation occures.

Does write operations will be executed eventually?

Comment: This says it best: _In other words, it is conceivable that one thread might be continuously starved because other threads always manage to arbitrarily get the lock instead of it._

Comment: @Sotirios is it might be or it isguaranteed?

Comment: @Sotirios, marked topic is not duplicate.

Comment: _might be_ means _might be_.